# Yii2 Active field checkbox checked by default in create

Tags: checkbox, yii2

My problem here is different than other problems addresses in other questions. My problem is that the active field value is taken from another model than the creation model. It looks like the following:

```
...
foreach ($section->cavities as $cavity) {
      $tr[$i] .= '<td>'.$form->field($cavityJob[$j], "[$j]cavity_id")->checkbox(['value' => $cavity->id, 'label' => $cavity->title.$section->title]).'</td>';
      $i++;
      $j++;
    } 
...
```

Notice here there are two models:

1. `$cavityJob`: the creation of field model
2. `$cavity`: which supply the value of the field through its `id` property

On create action I got the checkbox unchecked and I want them to be checked by default. I tried to place `'checked' => 'checked'` in the options array of the field but it did not succeed in make checkbox checked by default.

Comment: Have you tried 'checked' => true in options of checkbox?

Comment: Yes I have tried it.

Comment: I dont know how it's work for you,but normal cases when you load model first time at the time give checkbox field value 1.In model not in form

Answer (score 0):

Yoiu should assign true to the field

```
$model->cavity_id = true;
```

and you can assign the default value in model rule

```
 ['cavity_id', 'default', 'value' =>true],
```

Comment: `$cavityJob` is not a field. It is a model.

Comment: The model is many to many conjugation table. i.e there is only two properties of the model (two fields of the table) `job_id` and `cavity_id` additionally the count of `cavity_id`s related to `job_id` are fixed number. So, I'd liked to make a dashboard like with checkboxes. I rethink in it again and I find that it will be so difficult to make CRUD with such design, for example, update, in that case, may mean delete and this will make another problem in rendering deleted items to restore them again. So I decided to add third property named `status` to handle this task as a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$model->myAttribute = true; // or 1, or '1'

echo $form->field($model, 'myAttribute')->checkbox(); // checked ckeckbox
```